# Изображение как фон для tabBar

Tags: ios, swift

Я использую [PTCardTabBar](https://github.com/marcmora/PTCardTabBar) как `tabBar` в своем приложении. Но мне нужно использовать изображение в качестве фона для моего tabBar. Но чтобы я не пытался это делать, я не могу использовать изображения в качестве фона `PTCardTabBar`. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Глядя на пример, достаточно добавить на `customTabBar` в `PTTabBarViewController`:

```
let someImageView = UIImageView(image: <your_UIImage>)
someImageView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
customTabBar.addSubview(someImageView)
```

Comment: Не работает. Я уже пытался решить проблему через `patternImage`. Но тоже не помогает. Хотя по идее это должно сработать. Может я не туда добавляю свою картинку? Я ее добавляю в основной проект, а не в `Pods`. Хотя тогда бы приложение вылетало, если бы изображение не было найдено?

Comment: @User , добавьте примеры кода. В идеале, минимальный проект где воспроизводится Ваша проблема